# Remove brackets from argv string

Tags: python, argv, sys

I am new to Python. I'm running Raspbian and calling a Python script this way:

```
python testarguments.py "Here is a test parameter"
```

My script:

```
import sys
print sys.argv[1:]
```

Output:

```
['Here is a test parameter']
```

**Question:**
What is the most efficient way to remove beginning and ending brackets and single quotes from `sys.argv` output?

Comment: You are printing a _list_.

Comment: Ok, was following a tutorial, so thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @blackairplane I didn't downvote, but some would think that it perhaps lacked a little research effort.

Comment: And a certain assumption resulted in a downvote from you.

Comment: @AlexThornton Thanks for the clarification. The tutorial I was following seemed to be misleading, so I appreciate the help. I'll mark question as answered as soon as SO allows me to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are slicing with

```
sys.argv[1:]
```

It means that get all the elements from 1 till the end of the sequence. That is why it creates a new list.

To get only the first item, simply do

```
sys.argv[1]
```

This will get the element at index 1.

Answer (score 2):

The `:` sort of means 'and onwards' so it of course will return a `list`. Just do:

```
>>> sys.argv[1]
'Here is a test parameter'
```

Thus returning your first argument to executing the program, not a part of the list.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers have addressed the actual issue for you, but in case you ever do encounter a string that contains characters you want to remove (like square brackets, for example), you could do the following:

```
my_str = "['Here is a test parameter']"
my_str.translate(None, "[]")
```

In other words, if the output you saw were actually a string, you could use the translate method to get what you wanted.